# Facebook Login App VS Website

Tags: php, android, sql, facebook, authentication

I am using this facebook php login plugin..

http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php/

If you are on a phone browser (php website) and click login you will be redirected to the facebook.com login webpage.. Is there a way to redirect my website's facebook login to the facebook app to give us permissions (where I am already logged in eventhough facebook.com shows the opposite)?

Hope it's clear :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

AFAIK it is not possible to tell the phone to use the native Facebook App if you are running a website.

**OLD ANSWER:**

Use the official Facebook SDK.

Take a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

> The SDK has two different kinds of login dialogs you can use in you
>   app. The SDK automatically determines which Facebook for Android
>   application is on a device, and displays one of two dialogs:
>
> WebView Login - If no Facebook for Android app on a device, people see
>   a web login dialog inside a WebView.
>
> Native Login - If the user has Facebook for Android 1.9.X or older,
>   the SDK switches to Facebook for Android and shows a native login
>   dialog inside the Facebook for Android app.